# How to generate graph with maximum relaxation?

Tags: algorithm, graph, dijkstra

There is a [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://goo.gl/FP4Hi). I want to generate graph with given `|E|` and `|V|`, in which the algorithm perform maximum number of relaxations: `alt ← dist[u] + length(u, v)`.

This is a `ACM problem`. But I have no idea how to solve it. I look forward to any ideas.

`Example`. Let `|V| = 4` and `|E| = 3`. Than, I looking for a graph with the following edges and weight (`v1, v2, w`):

`(1, 2, 0)`

`(1, 3, 1`)

`(1, 4, 2`)

Comment: Maximum number of relaxations to find the shortest path from `1` to `N`?

Comment: @IVlad, yep, you are absolutely right.

Answer (score 5):

This looks like it might work, although I didn't give it much thought yet.

Add edges `(1, 2, 1); (1, 3, 2); ...; (1, N, k)`.

If not done, add edges `(2, 3, cost(1, 3) - 2); (2, 4, cost(1, 4) - 2); ...`

If not done, add edges `(3, 4, cost(1, 4) - 3); ...`

And so on, until done.

Your graph will look like:

```
 4---------------
 |        \     |
 |         |    |
(3)       (1)   |
 |         |    |
 |         |    |
 1 --(1)-- 2   (0) 
 |         |    |
 |         |    |
(2)       (0)   |
 |         |    |
 |        /     |
 3---------------
```

First, the algorithm will relax all nodes connected to node `1`:

```
d[4] = 3
d[2] = 1
d[3] = 2
```

Then, all those connected to node 2:

```
d[3] = 1
d[4] = 2
```

Then all those connected to node 3

```
d[4] = 2
```

So we did `6` relaxations: one for each edge. This is the maximum possible.